# SVG Circles - Animate Segments? (Doughnut Chart)

Tags: svg, svg-animate

```
<svg width="210px" height="210px" viewBox="0 0 210 210" class="donut">
<circle class="donut-ring" cx="105" cy="105" r="95" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="20"></circle>
<circle class="donut-segment" cx="105" cy="105" r="95" fill="transparent" stroke="#1a1a1a" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="149.22565104551518 447.67695313654554" stroke-dashoffset="150"></circle>
<circle class="donut-segment" cx="105" cy="105" r="95" fill="transparent" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="149.22565104551518 447.67695313654554" stroke-dashoffset="597.6769531365455"></circle>
<circle class="donut-segment" cx="105" cy="105" r="95" fill="transparent" stroke="#434343" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="298.45130209103036 298.45130209103036" stroke-dashoffset="448.45130209103036"></circle>
</svg>
```

Basically my problem is iv'e created a dynamic doughnut chart where the segments are automatically generated (class="donut-segment"). I need to make all the segments animate simultaneously from their start point to their end point. Iv'e done some pretty extensive searching but i can't find a example quite like mine. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated or just a point in the right direction.

I need the end result to have this effect
https://codepen.io/ksksoft/pen/xsnmp

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Transitioned Stroke-DashArray from "0 and 600" into their proper values, and also transitioned the strokeDashOffset from 0 to its proper value